# What is the difference between item content type and document content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What is the difference between item content type and document content type?. Can list item associated with item content type be moved to document library with document library which is having a document content type?..please help

Answer (score 0):

An item is equivalent to a row in a table, or a record in a database. It consists of columns of metadata. The tables in which they reside in SharePoint are called lists.

A document is a type of item, with additional functionality. This additional functionality depends on the fact that a document always has an associated file. In SharePoint, documents only exist in a special type of list called a document library.

Instead of a record in a database, a document is more like a file in a file system; not only does it have columns of metadata, it also has an underlying file (the document itself). It can't exist without that underlying file.

Only items of the document content type, or items whose content type inherits from the document content type, can be placed in document libraries. Items with content types that do not inherit from the Document content type cannot exist in document libraries because they do not have that necessary file association.